# Low ontouchmove interval on Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I'm playing around with HTML5 canvas and bumped into something which I believe is a performance issue on Android browser (and/or JavaScript implementation).

I'm implementing a freehand sketch web application where user can draw using his finger - have a look at draft on http://www.matkakuume.net/freehand.html. The implementation itself works fine but it doesn't seem to keep up when finger is moved rapidly. For example when drawing a circle the end result looks more like a polygon (which it effectively is supposed to be, but I was kinda hoping there would be more angles...)

As mentioned, this is an Android related problem as the implementation works fine on desktop and on iPhone. I've explained to myself that when user moves the finger on screen the ontouchmove events are not triggered rapidly enough to render the path smoothly.

Can someone guarantee that this is the case or am I on the wrong tracks here?

Answer (score 0):

It is long ago since you posted, but for future readers: 
http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html

Android batches touch events, a MotionEvent does not only contain one coordinate but multiple coordidates. You have to look up all of them.